# The CHUCK on my bench-top drill press slips. (Not the bit in my Chuck). How do I fix this?

Tags: drill

I have a bench top Craftsman Drill Press. The CHUCK slips when I try to drill anything other than lightest work. How do I fix this, get chuck firmly attached to shaft of the drill press?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have some photos?

Comment: For those chucks, firmly attach and on tight can be different.  They usually need a very good wack to seat them properly.  If the slippage has gone long enough there might some damage/change of diameters of the hole and pin.

Comment: What model number is your **specific** craftsman drill press? They put that name on a lot of different models over the years

Answer (score 1):

Check your belt tension, remove the chuck, and clean the mating surfaces. Reapply the scrap wood buffer by tapping the chuck back onto the shaft and tapping on the other side of the board.

Answer (score 1):

you don't, other than by getting something better than craftsman

there's a reason sears went bankrupt and sold off craftsman

> As of May 2023, there are 11 total Sears stores remaining, with 10 in the mainland US and one location in the US territory of Puerto Rico.

Comment: haha -1 = truth hurts. best of luck.

Comment: Craftsman is garbage +1

Comment: thought of answering with only `search on youtube`.   I'm not familiar with all possible ways benchtop drill presses are made, but for the way one would expect with regards to quality when you say `not the bit in my chuck` then you are saying the chuck is spinning on the spindle and that should not happen.  Replace the spindle.  U probably can't on that craftsman.  If it's 50 years old then it may have been good quality and couldve been replaced but then my answer qualifies cause u likely won't find replacement parts given sears bankruptcy and sell off of craftsman

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnXGy_-SAGk

Comment: the fact that its slipping also means its very likely to not spin true (has runout).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a typical chuck that's press fit on a taper, remove it, clean both parts, check for damage preventing the parts from fully mating, clean up the damage or replace the damaged parts, and reassemble (with **no** lubrication.)